# Searching for the form of Bayesian estimator

Tags: statistics, bayesian, estimation

We consider problem of estimation $\theta$ parameter based on sample $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ with density $f(x, \theta)$. Our loss function is given by $L(\theta,a)=b\{exp[c(a-\theta)]-c(a-\theta)-1\}$ for constants $b,c>0$. $\pi$ is a priori distribution of $\theta$.
Our goal is to determine the form of the Bayesian estimator of $\theta$ parameter for a priori distribution $\pi$ with loss function mentioned above. Any suggestions how to find this?

Comment: Without the explicit knowledge of $f$ and $\pi$, the only thing one can say is "write the corresponding integral and try to minimize it by whatever techniques might be available".

Comment: What do you mean by 'the corresponding integral'?

Comment: $\int[\prod_j f(X_j,\theta)]L(\theta,\hat\theta)d\pi(\theta)$